# Looking for resources regarding deploying Tenable scanners to already extant GCP Compute Engine VMs and GKE clusters

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine, automated-install

I am a GCP(Google Cloud Platform) newb, who has been tasked with figuring out how to deploy Tenable scanner agents to already extant GCP Compute Engine instances and GKE(Google Kubernetes Engine) clusters.

I have been looking for instructional online pertaining to deploying/installing applications to stand alone Compute Instances and GKE containers en masse and in an automated fashion; to as of yet no avail.

Any insight or instructionals that would help me in my task would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!!!

Comment: Use your existing configuration management system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...as it turns out, there is no way "canned" way to do this.  Neither Tenable.io nor Tenable.sc possesses the functionality to "push out" agents to discovered assets.
The installation of these agents within certain contexts could definitely be automated, but there exists on feature to accomplish this task via GCP, Tenable, or some other orchestration tool such that little next to no configuration on behalf of the user/engineer is required.